# Unable to cast object of type 'system.IO.DirectoryInfo' to type 'System.IO.FileInfo'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm getting an error in the where clause in the below code. The error states:
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' to type 'System.IO.FileInfo'

```vb
Try
    Dim query As MySqlCommand = SQLConnection.CreateCommand
    Dim dir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\10.2.1.40\IT\BACKUPDATA\MBP_DATA\")
    For Each fi As FileInfo In dir.GetFileSystemInfos
        query.CommandText = "UPDATE backup_db set tgl = @date1, ukuran = @ukuran, issaturday = @issaturday, iseom = @iseom,  pic = @pic
'                                        WHERE ukuran = 0 and tgl = @date1"
        query.Parameters.Clear()
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", fi.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ukuran", fi.Length)
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@issaturday", "0")
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iseom", "0")
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", "Carles")
        query.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Try
```

Comment: Maybe you should read what that `GetFileSystemInfos` actually does.

Comment: You really shouldn't store dates as strings in a database. Also, although using SQL parameters is good, using AddWithValue is likely to cause you problems: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetFileSystemInfos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns an array of  [`FileSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)  which is not [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
For Each fi As FileSystemInfo In dir.GetFileSystemInfos()
   ' ... '
Next
```

A `FileInfo` is also an `FileSystemInfo` because it's a child class but not vice-versa. `DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos` returns files and directories. So you can't cast them to `FileInfo`.

But since you need the `Length` i assume you actually need only files. Then use `GetFiles`:

```
For Each fi As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles()
   ' ... '
Next
```